# Horizontal calendar using PHP

Tags: calendar

You can see what I am trying to make here http://perthurbanist.com/website/calendarloader.php. Basically it is a horizontal calendar and you will use arrows to move. What I want to do is have the code display all the months horizontally along with all the days (starting from the current month and day). I know how to get the current day using the date function but I don't know how to make the calendar start at that date. I also want it to load lots of months (maybe 2-3 years worth). How do I do those two things.

```
<?php
$showday = date("j");
$displaymonth = date("M");
$showmonth = date("n");
$showyear = date("Y");

$day_count = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $showmonth, $showyear);

echo '<ul class="calendarnavigation">';
echo '<li class="month">' . $displaymonth . '</li>';

for($i=1; $i<= $day_count; $i++) {
echo '<li>' . $i . '</li>';
}

echo '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know (or are able to calculate how far ahead you want to go in days you could try this:

```
for($i=0; $i<$numberOfDays; $i++)
{
    $timestamp=mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")+$i,date("Y"));
    $day=date("d", $timestamp);
    $month=date("m", $timestamp);
    $year=date("Y", $timestamp);

    ...Your display stuff here...

}
```

On each iteration of the loop the `$timestamp` will advance one day and using it in your `date` functions will give you the information about the date that you need to create your display.

Maybe in your case you can use

```
echo '<ul class="calendarnavigation">';

for($i=0; $i<$numberOfDays; $i++)
{
    $timestamp=mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")+$i,date("Y"));
    $showday=date("j", $timestamp);
    $displaymonth=date("M", $timestamp);
    $showmonth=date("n", $timestamp);
    $showyear=date("Y", $timestamp);

    if($showday=="1")
    {
        echo '<li>'.$displaymonth.'</li>';
    }

    echo '<li>'.$showday.'</li>';

}

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: awesome! do you have any recommendations on how i should do the navigation? i want to click on the arrows and have it scroll to show more but i want to make a new month title show up so you know what month it is.

Comment: also it says if($showday=="1") how do i make this display on the first month even if the day is something like 23rd?

Comment: @user1691978 You could change the condition to `if($showday=="1" || $i==0)` to make the month appear at the start regardless of date. Maybe that could appear outside of the loop and outside of the `ul` as a fixed element that you could change using the javascript you use to do the scrolling.

Comment: I appear to have suffered a random drive-by down-vote. Does the downvoter care to explain his/her objection?